# Why does my Belkin Play router regularly stop working for a few minutes at a time?

Tags: router, interference, dual-band

I recently purchased a Belking Play dual-band router for my home. About every few hours, the router stops working or "cuts out" for several minutes before coming back online automatically.

My old one did this as well. I figured out a main problem was my wireless home phone, which sends a 2.4GHz signal. Anytime someone would call the phone, my router would get interrupted. Therefore, I unplugged this phone and got a wired phone. Unfortunately, my wired phone has the same problem. Therefore, I unplugged the wired phone. Unfortunately, my router still has regular issues. I live in a home with neighbors within close proximity to me, so it might be possible that their devices are the ones causing me problems.

How can I determine what is causing my router problems? I thought that the point of a dual-band router was that if a signal was interfering on one band then it would be uninterrupted on another. However, it seems that is not the case.

Does anyone have any tips on how to troubleshoot this or any knowledge you can share to properly set my expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out what the issue was. I never installed the DSL filters that came with my DSL Modem. By putting a DSL filter on each of my phones' connections, I stopped getting interrupted Internet service every time someone called.

Answer (score 1):

This may be difficult to diagnose but you should start with a wifi analyzer. Check to make sure there are no other AP's in the area broadcasting on the same channel as you. If there is none the next step would be trial and error. Without being able to see what channels your neighbors phones are on you will have to try the channels one by one. This happened to me, it took me three or four try's but I finally found a channel no one else was using. I would suggest starting at 1 and just working your way up from there.